# Best way to highlight current page in Rails 3? -- apply a css class to links conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Some Page", some_path %>
```

**How do I apply a css class `current` using the `current_page?‎` helper method?**

Or if some other better way is available?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def cp(path)
  "current" if current_page?(path)
end
```

In your views:

```
<%= link_to "All Posts", posts_path, class: cp(posts_path) %>
```

Basically write a simple wrapper around it. Additionally you could extend the method to allow additional classes to be applied by adding arguments. Keeps the views concise/dry. Or, without extending the method, you could just do simple String interpolation like so to add additional classes:

```
<%= link_to "All Posts", posts_path, class: "#{cp(posts_path)} additional_class" %>
```

Comment: Would current_page need options or just like that it should work? In the other answer I had to add the options to make it work.

Comment: Ah sorry. I forgot about that. Yes you pass it in. I have updated the post with a more clear example using the typical "PostsController".

Comment: works great. however in my case @rderoldan1 's   answer below works better since I have a link in navbar and I want it to be highlighted on both index and a show page. (in this case same navbar is visible on both)

Answer (score 18):

In my case I have a lot of name spaced controllers, that is why I like to show if the current view also is in the Menu Path, I had use the solution of Michael van Rooijen and then I customize for my case.

#### Helper

```
def cp(path)
  "current" if request.url.include?(path)
end
```

#### View

```
<%= link_to "All Posts", posts_path, class: cp(posts_path) %>
```

Now if my menu bar is /users and my current page is /users/10/post also the link /users is set with "current" class

Comment: happy I found this. This was perfect for what I needed!

Comment: real nice - than you

Answer (score 13):

I branched off of Michael's answer and tweaked the helper:

```
def active_class?(*paths)
  active = false
  paths.each { |path| active ||= current_page?(path) }
  active ? 'active' : nil
end
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
<%= link_to "Bookings", bookings_path, class: active_class?(bookings_path) %>
```

You can pass multiple paths to it in case you have a tab which could be rendered by multiple views:

```
<%= content_tag :li, class: active_class?(bookings_path, action: 'new') %>
```

And the great thing about this is if the conditions are `false`, it will insert `nil`. Why is this good? Well, if you provide `class` with `nil` it won't include the class attribute on the tag at all. Bonus!

Comment: In a fresh rails 4 app, current_page? appears to be missing

Comment: It's [still there](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F). Make sure you're in a view context.

Answer (score 5):

In the interest of not having to repeat your self too much by having to check current_page inside the `link_to` method all the time, here's a custom helper that you can use (put this in   `app/views/helpers/application_helpers.rb`

```
def link_to_active_class(name, active_class_names, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
  html_options[:class] = html_options[:class].to_s + active_class_names if current_page?(options.to_s)
  link_to name, options, html_options, &block
end
```

Example usage:

```
<div> <%= link_to_active_class('Dashboard', 'bright_blue', dashboard_path, class: 'link_decor') </div>
```

if you are on `http://example.com/dashboard`, then it should return:

```
<div> <a href='/dashboard' class='link_decor bright_blue'>Dashboard</a> </div>
```

Regards.

Comment: This answer is better than the chosen one ! Perfect for .active class on navbar !

Comment: this is the best answer +1

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it this way :

```
<%= link_to "Some Page", some_path, :class => current_page? ? "current" : "" %>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just added the condition to your code... ```<%= link_to "Some Page", some_path, :class => current_page?(some_path) ? "current" : "" %>```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to combine a couple of the mentioned techniques with my own needs.

```
def current_page(path)
  'current' if current_page?(path)
end

def create_nav_link(string, path, method)
  link_to string, path, data: { hover: string }, method: method
end

def create_nav_item(string, path, method = nil)
  content_tag :li, create_nav_link(string, path, method), class: current_page(path)
end
```

Basically it allows you to use it like this:
`create_nav_item("profile", profile_path)` which will result in:
`<li><a href="/profile" data-hover="Profile">Profile</a></li>`,

or `<li class="current"><a href="/profile" data-hover="Profile">Profile</a></li>` if this is the current page.

I didn't use `request.url.include?(path)` since it will also always highlight the "Home" button, and I couldn't think of a work around by far.

Answer (score 0):

A variant to Eric Boehs solution (the most robust one IMHO), if you are linking directly to an object of the class (i.e. you don't show the index), with an added application helper:

```
def booking_link
 Booking.find(8)
end
```

You can use the following in the view (the *dd* is used in the context of zurb foundation)

```
<%= content_tag :dd, link_to(t('hints.book'), booking_link), class: active_class?(booking_path) %>-
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if would be good idea if you generate whole `link_to` from your helper method. Why to repeat the same code ( :-) DRY principle)

```
def create_link(text, path)
  class_name = current_page?(path) ? 'current' : 'any_other_class'

  link_to text, path, class: class_name
end
```

Now you can use like:

`<%= create_link 'xyz', any_path %>` (in views) which would render as `<a href="/any" class="current">xyz</a>`

Hope it helps!