# Hide certain content depending on active page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm new to Rails and am building a basic personal site.  I have a container on the home page serving as a full-screen color-blocked welcome area.  It's in my application.html.erb in the layout folder, but only want it to appear when the user is on home.html.erb (Having to put in the application file to allow it to be full-width).  I thought I could do it with an <% if %><% else %> Ruby statement, but nothing I'm writing is getting it to work.  I may be trying to handle this the wrong way, though, so I appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552763/best-way-to-highlight-current-page-in-rails-3-apply-a-css-class-to-links-con

Please do a search before polluting SO with repeated questions.

Comment: I actually searched for a while because I didn't want to post if it's already been asked, but I came up empty.  I was only finding how to hide user logins, info, etc., and not certain content on pages.  I'm not sure what you searched to find that, but I appreciate it.

Comment: Why did you put the block in application.html.erb when you only want it to appear on one page?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap framework to get it put together as quickly as possible right now with my limited knowledge.  And to keep the color-block full-width it can't be in a container, which if I put it on the home page, it'd be in a container automatically when called in the yield.  Might not be going about it the correct way, but I'm extremely new to Rails and this framework.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

It detects which route you are on, so you can use that in your 'if' statement.

Another option, if you have different types of content depending on the page, is to use [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method) to show different stuff in that section without using a chain of if/else statement (if it gets more complicated that either/or).

Comment: FYI, you can't use the `current_page?` method with blank parameters (i.e. you have to explicitly tell it to check if it's something). So if you're looking to OBTAIN which controller or which action, use `controller_name` and `action_name`. If you're using `action_name`, you most likely want to do an `&&` with the `controller_name`