# How to use the `link_to_unless_current` helper to work for both current or root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper

I am setting up my navbar `link_to`'s and I'm trying to stop a link being rendered if current_path is the same as link_path or if current path is the same as root path, as root path is defined as that same as the link path, as below:

_navbarhtml.erb

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <% if user_signed_in? %>               
           <li><%= link_to_unless_current('My Quotes', quotes_path(current_user)) do %></li>
         <% end %>
           <li><%= link_to_unless_current('New Quote', new_quote_path) do %></li>
         <% end %>
           <li><%= link_to('My Account', edit_user_registration_path) %></li>
           <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
         <% else %>
           <li><%= link_to('Sign in', new_user_session_path) %></li>
           <li><%= link_to('Sign up', new_user_registration_path) %></li>
         <% end %>
        </li>
```

routes.rb

```
root    'quotes#new'
```

Any neat suggestions as to how to nicely write this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to highlight current page in Rails 3? -- apply a css class to links conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552763/best-way-to-highlight-current-page-in-rails-3-apply-a-css-class-to-links-con)

Comment: Thanks for the link, a nice solution, I'd like to try to use the rails helper though to do this, in the end I wrote a helper method as written below and suggested by @Surya

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`current_page?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F). Create a helper method like so:

```
def link_to_unless_current(text, url, options={})
  if current_page?(url)
    # do something else? maybe create a text which does not have a link?
  else
    link_to text, url, options
  end
end
```

Now, view will be like:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current('My Quotes', quotes_path(current_user)) %>
```

Feel free to change the name of helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Surya, this is the way i got it to work in the end:

application_helper.rb

```
def link_to_unless_current_or_root(text, url)
    if current_page?(url) 

    elsif current_page?(root_path)

    else
        link_to text, url
    end
end
```

_navbar.html.erb

```
<li><%= link_to_unless_current_or_root('New Quote', new_quote_path) %></li>
```